# Fritzing files of Adafruit T-Cobber Plus for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3

I cannot find Fritzing files of Adafruit T-Cobber Plus for Raspberry Pi 3. I'd like such set (main board + cable + t-clobber + breadboard):

[image]

The official site (http://fritzing.org/projects/raspberry-pi-3) has a good image, but wrong files for download. I found a few files at https://github.com/adafruit/Fritzing-Library/ and https://github.com/anuditnagar/fritzing , but they are not right either: it doesn't connect to breadboard automatically, or I do it manually and took a mess.

Is there any ideas where is good fritzing for it? Source of any project with t-clobber available for editing also will be good.

Comment: Usually requests for off-site resources are considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one lined up perfectly :

https://github.com/adafruit/Fritzing-Library/blob/master/parts/Adafruit%20T-Cobbler%20Plus.fzpz

[image]

Do you need the Pi and ribbon cable - as every connection is labeled on the Cobble Plus?